# How to input two consecutive values from a list into a method? (Java)

Tags: java, list

So I have a list where every odd number value is a phone number and every even number value is a house number.

i.e (888-888-888, 1642, 777-777-777, 5623...)

I have to insert those values into a method that goes something like

aMethod(house number, phone number)

so basically the values are flipped.

Am I able to flip and insert two values into one method using only one for-loop? If so, how? I'm not too advanced with Java so a simple solution would help.

Comment: add some code that you have written so far

Comment: This site is unsuitable for teaching programming basics. Talk to your teacher instead.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, if everything in list in a proper order, do:

```
int n = list.size();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 2)
    aMethod(list.get(i + 1), list.get(i));
```